# This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment only on some machines

Tags: angular, innerhtml, content-security-policy

I am working in an Angular project that is receiving html code from an API and then putting it into the 'innerHTML' of a Mat Dialog. I have set it up to use a Dom sanitizer and using the function 'bypassSecurityTrustHtml'. And adjusted my CSP in my angular.json file accordingly to allow it to open and display correctly on my local machine, as well as another machine. I have also verified most of my coworkers can view it without issue.

However 2 of my coworkers are having issues. When they try to display the same Html, they are receiving an error: "Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': This document requires 'TrustedHTML assignment.'

My question is does anyone know what would cause this to behave like this on only certain machines. Everyone is using Chrome. It's just a small selection of people that it isn't working for.

Comment: Had they both tried clean, rebuild the project and then hard reset the chrome cache? Also make sure their chrome version is similar to yours, and try Incognito.

Comment: Chrome is often running experiments with new code on a percentage of users to test out the impact of future functionality.